# Convert List<object> to List of some type known at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I'm trying to convert a string delimited by a comma to a list of some type.

```
private static void SetPropertyValue(this object obj, PropertyInfo propInfo, object value)
{
    if (propInfo.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        var listType = propInfo.PropertyType.GetCollectionType();
        var listValue = value.ToString().Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, listType, null)).ToList();

        propInfo.SetValue(obj, listValue, null);
    }
    
    //....
}

public static Type GetCollectionType(this Type type)
{
    foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
            interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            == typeof(IList<>))
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Message is irrelevant");
}
```

Splitting the string and converting each value with Convert.ChangeType works well, but creates a `List<object>`. I need some way of generating a `List<PropType>` in order for the SetValue call to work correctly.

If you were to run this code with a `List<string>` property, you would receive an ArgumentException as the `List<object>` cannot be converted to a `List<string>`.

Comment: I suspect you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method...

Comment: You could call `Enumerable.Cast` method using reflection and pass `listType` as generic type `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this by making my SetPropertyValue method accept a generic type `T` and creating a `List<T>`.

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(object obj, PropertyInfo propInfo, object value)
{
    if (propInfo.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        List<T> listValue = value.ToString()
            .Split(',')
            .Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T), null))
            .ToList();

        propInfo.SetValue(obj, listValue, null);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I can then call the method using reflection to pass a Type variable as `T`.

```
var type = property.PropertyType.GetCollectionType();
var method = typeof(TypeExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(TypeExtensions.SetPropertyValue));
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(obj, new object[] { obj, property, value });
```